# "Management group does not have any valid subscriptions" using Azure Cost Analysis

Tags: azure, cost-management

I have created a management group and added several subscriptions. When I go to Cost Analysis and select the new MG as a scope, I get the "Management group does not have any valid subscriptions" error and the below screen shot. I can see Cost Anslysis for each individual subscription but get the error when I add even one to the MG. I'm an Azure Global administrator and hold the owner role to each subscription in question.

[image]

I've verified my permissions (owner) added each subscription individually to the MG with the same results. There's an other post on Stack Overflow with this issue but it talks about multiple directories. I do have multiple directories but only one contains my subscriptions and billing profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the beginning.

Go to Cost Management + Billing > Billing scopes and select the right billing scope.

[image]

Now go into Cost Analysis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works fine, it's when I want to go to Cost Analysis for a management group, not a billing scope.

Comment: Let me try to reproduce this on my side

Comment: Oh, yeah! I have the same error. Open a ticket with Microsoft